# What is a mod b if a < b?

Tags: mathematical-foundations

So when you are decrypting an encryption with modular arithmetic, I know the modulus operator (%) gives the remainder of a/b, but what if a is less than b?

For example, 5%2 is 1, since the answer is 2 remainder 1. But for something like 2%9, how do you find the answer?

Comment: Questions about C++ in particular are offtopic here, and the general question is a pure mathematics question. Do you want me to migrate this to [SO] or [math.SE]?

Answer (score 7):

If $a,b$ are both positive integers, then we can always write $a = kb+\ell$ where $0 \leq \ell < b$. We call $\ell$ the *remainder* and $k$ the *quotient*. In your first example, $5 = 2 \cdot 2 + 1$ so `5 % 2 == 1`. In your second example, $2 = 0 \cdot 9 + 2$, so `2 % 9 == 2`. More generally, if $a < b$ then `a % b == a`.

There is also a rule for signed integers, but unfortunately I can't remember it. Also, `0 % x == 0` whenever $x \neq 0$, and `x % 0` will cause an exception ("division by zero").

Comment: With signed integers it becomes [messy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50433446/3234959) and different programming languages use a different operator.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is 9.  2 / 9 is 0r9.  The modulus operator returns the remainder of integer division, since 9 goes into 2 0 times the operator returns 9.